# How to solve this error in Application Express?

Tags: oracle-apex

[How to solve the add cart problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xvoQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is a poorly asked question, but here's your answer

http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2017/01/escape-special-characters-apex-demo.html

You need to provide more details about how you came to your problem, and what you're trying to do. You're lucky a picture paints a thousand words, and this is a common problem with people learning the tool.